# Addition items in list Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm working with lists in Racket, and I was doing a function to additions items.
I did

```
(define (iter lst [acc '()])
  (if (null? lst)
      (append (list acc))
      (iter10 (cdr lst) (append acc (caar lst)))))
```

and i have output:

```
(iter10 '(((1 2)(3 4)(5 6))((7 8)(9 10)(11 12))))
'((1 2 7 8))
```

but i want output:

```
(iter10 '(((1 2)(3 4)(5 6))((7 8)(9 10)(11 12))))
'((1 2 7 8) (3 4 9 10) (5 6 11 12))
```

```
(iter10 '(((1 2)(3 4)(5 6))((7 8)(9 10)(11 12))((1 2)(3 4)(5 6))))
'((1 2 7 8 1 2) (3 4 9 10 3 4) (5 6 11 12 5 6))
```

I know it's because of the use of caar, but I don't know how to do it any other way.
There is a main list in which there are several list. I want all elements to be connected by position. And that the number of main list could be any. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break this problem into two parts:

- Use [`apply map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) idiom to create groups of lists with same position:

```
> (apply map list '(((1 2)(3 4)(5 6))((7 8)(9 10)(11 12))))
'(((1 2) (7 8)) ((3 4) (9 10)) ((5 6) (11 12)))
```

- Use [`append`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._append%29%29) to append all lists in group into one list:

```
> (map (lambda (group) (apply append group))
       '(((1 2) (7 8)) ((3 4) (9 10)) ((5 6) (11 12))))
'((1 2 7 8) (3 4 9 10) (5 6 11 12))
```

Then combine these two parts into one function:

```
(define (iter10 lst)
  (map (lambda (group) (apply append group))
       (apply map list lst)))
```

Tests:

```
> (iter10 '(((1 2)(3 4)(5 6))((7 8)(9 10)(11 12))))
'((1 2 7 8) (3 4 9 10) (5 6 11 12))

> (iter10 '(((1 2)(3 4)(5 6))((7 8)(9 10)(11 12))((1 2)(3 4)(5 6))))
'((1 2 7 8 1 2) (3 4 9 10 3 4) (5 6 11 12 5 6))
```

Comment: Děkuji mnohokrát!

Comment: @Smutna_zabka Není zač / You're welcome :D